# How To Convert String ' dd/mm/yy hh:MM:ss ' to Date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I have Done this

```
    var d='dd/mm/yy hh:MM:ss';
    var d1=d.split(" ");
    var date=d1[0].split("/");
    var time=d1[1].split(":");
    var dd=date[0];
    var mm=date[1]-1;
    var yy=date[2];
    var hh=time[0];
    var min=time[1];
    var ss=time[2];
    var fromdt= new Date("20"+yy,mm-1,dd,hh,min,ss);
```

Is there Any way to do it using JQuery OR JavaScript?

Comment: mm-1 is typed Mistakenly*

Comment: You can edit your question and correct any errors.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are looking for alternatives in jquery or Javascript , then you can go with [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/),where you can **Parse**, **Validate**, **Manipulate**, and **Display** dates in JavaScript.

example:

```
  var date= moment("06/06/2015 11:11:11").format('DD-MMM-YYYY');
```

Comment: This example should show using a format specifier as the second parameter to the `moment` function.  See the "Warning" [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/).

Comment: Yes its a **Deprecation Warning**: it is due to the format of date refer this link https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 ,here they already provided a solution for it @MattJohnson

Answer (score 11):

This will work regardless of timezone for the format `dd/mm/yyy hh:mm:ss` only. It also does not rely on third party packages:

```js
let dtStr = "12/03/2010 09:55:35"

console.log(strToDate(dtStr));  // Fri Mar 12 2010 09:55:35

function strToDate(dtStr) {
  if (!dtStr) return null
  let dateParts = dtStr.split("/");
  let timeParts = dateParts[2].split(" ")[1].split(":");
  dateParts[2] = dateParts[2].split(" ")[0];
  // month is 0-based, that's why we need dataParts[1] - 1
  return dateObject = new Date(+dateParts[2], dateParts[1] - 1, +dateParts[0], timeParts[0], timeParts[1], timeParts[2]);
}
```

Comment: How to treat null?

Comment: @O'DaneBrissett edited, though the exact answer depends on your implementation. If this is going to a database with a non-nullable constraint you'll likely want to add an if statement in the first line of the function returning `new Date(dtStr)` which will just give you the unix timestamp. Otherwise likely best just to return null (as a null string logically resolves to a null date).

Answer (score 7):

How about [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)?

```
new Date( Date.parse("05/12/05 11:11:11") );
// Thu May 12 2005 11:11:11 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

The output produced is in local timezone and will differ in browsers in different timezones.

Answer (score 6):

We can convert any local date format to datetime datatype using moment js.

**Syntax:**

```
moment('<local date value>','<local date format>').format('<expected convert format>')
```

**Example:**

```
moment('26/05/1986 00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm').format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm");
```

then the output will be **05/26/1986 00:00**

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

`Date#parse` should be able to parse that if you split on a string. Id also recommend looking into the npm package moment for date manipulation

Answer (score 0):

From your code it seems that you are trying to convert string into date and also you are trying to fetch previous month. If yes then you can reconstruct your code as below:

```
Date.prototype.SubtractMonth = function(numberOfMonths) {
var d = this;
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - numberOfMonths);
return d;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
     var dateString='2015-06-17T18:30:12';
    var d = new Date(dateString);
    alert(d.SubtractMonth(1));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @sean-coley, your answer helped a lot, but it gives me changed (local) time with different timezone. I would also add Date.UTC to the new Date function so the result time will be the same as in input

```js
let dtStr = "12/03/2010 09:55:35"

console.log(strToDate(dtStr));  // Fri Mar 12 2010 09:55:35

function strToDate(dtStr) {
  if (!dtStr) return null
  let dateParts = dtStr.split("/");
  let timeParts = dateParts[2].split(" ")[1].split(":");
  dateParts[2] = dateParts[2].split(" ")[0];
  // month is 0-based, that's why we need dataParts[1] - 1
  return dateObject = new Date(Date.UTC(+dateParts[2], dateParts[1] - 1, +dateParts[0], timeParts[0], timeParts[1], timeParts[2]));
}
```