# JavaScript date and time formatting,

Tags: javascript, html, date, time, formatting

I have read a lot of thread about the subject, but i'm not much into programming... i've made some tests but never acheive what i wanted.

Here we have a html template we have to modify to suit our needs.

here the code i have to edit:

```
<p id="DATE"></p>
<script>
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("DATE").innerHTML = d.toString();
</script>
```

Its giving me the date OK...but not i the format i want...
the format i want is...  DD-MM-YYYY  HH:MM

Simple has that :)

Its been a couple of hours and i can't do it... Can anyone help with a code i just can copy/paste in my html file.

Comment: You should use momentjs https://momentjs.com/. Very easy to parse and format dates: `moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')`

Comment: There is a vanilla Javascript answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409299/how-to-get-current-formatted-date-dd-mm-yyyy-in-javascript-and-append-it-to-an-i)

Comment: no thanks... i've seen this answer too much..

Comment: there is already an answer here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30891884/how-to-convert-string-dd-mm-yy-hhmmss-to-date-in-javascript please make sure you search StackOverflow for questions first before posting.

Comment: I've seen dozens of thread taking about this... but i not good enough to implement this in my page... i mean, i'm tryng to copy paste section of codes, but its not working on my end. I'm really not good at programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As opposed to using an external JavaScript library for a simple task. You should be able to achieve the same with Vanilla js.

Refer to this:
[Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

In short:

```
var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var curr_hour = d.getHours();
var curr_min = d.getMinutes();
console.log(curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year + " " + curr_hour + ":" + curr_min);
```

The above snippet should have all the code you need.

For your specific implementation, you will need to do the below:

```
<script>
    var d = new Date();
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    var curr_hour = d.getHours();
    var curr_min = d.getMinutes();
    var formattedDate = curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year + " " + curr_hour + ":" + curr_min;
    document.getElementById("DATE").innerHTML = formattedDate;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A function for the format you require is fairly simple. The following will return a string for a provided Date, or the current date if none passed.

```js
function formatDate(date) {
  var d = date || new Date();
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'')+n}
  return z(d.getDate()) + '-' + 
         z(d.getMonth()+1) + '-' +
         d.getFullYear() + ' ' +
         z(d.getHours()) + ':' +
         z(d.getMinutes());
}
document.write(formatDate());
```

BTW, you can't use the same token for two separate parts. While there is no standard or even consistency for formatting tokens, your format would be more commonly expressed as:

```
DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm
```

Which is compatible with moment.js and a few others, though there are many other token sets to represent the same format.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal simply try following codes:

First of all, inside the head tag add the below line of code:

`<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>`

Finally, change your existing line of code:

`document.getElementById("DATE").innerHTML = moment(d).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM');`

Happy coding :)