# How to convert string into date formate in typescript

Tags: javascript

This is my HTML:

```
label for="simple-input" class="Label">{{item.name}}</label> 
<input type="date" class="Input" id="exampleInputName" value="new Date([value.valuwwe])">
```

Here is my JSON:

```
{
    "name": "Date Field",
    "namessId": 8717,
    "category": "Date Field",
    "categsssoryId": 8718,
    "descrssiption": "Date Field",
    "descriptionId": 8716,
    "specreType": 5,
    "maxValue": "6/7/2017 12:00:00 AM",
    "minValue": "6/7/2017 12:00:00 AM",
    "value": {
        "valuwwe": "01/01/0001 00:00:00",
        "vasslueId": 8719,
        "scssvId": 1007,
        "isDesfault": false
}
```

I am using `new date()`, but its not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript date and time formatting,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42774908/javascript-date-and-time-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, try

```
< ... value="new Date(item.value.valuwwe)">
```

Comment: value="new Date(item.value.valuwwe)">  i have tried this but not working